# Как решить задачу с использованием рекурсии?

Tags: java, рекурсия, biginteger, факториал

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить задачу с помощью рекурсии.

> Описание: Необходимо реализовать метод factorial, вычисляющий
> факториал заданного натурального числа.
>
> Факториал N вычисляется как 1 ⋅ 2 ⋅ ... ⋅ N. Необходимо использовать
> BigInteger.
>
> Пример ввода 1: 1
>
> Пример возвращаемого значения 1: 1
>
> Пример ввода 2: 3
>
> Пример возвращаемого значения 2: 6

Мое решение:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int value) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i <= value; i++)
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    return result;
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем решении нет рекурсии, рекурсия предполагает обращение функции к самой себе.
Пример реализации:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int value) {
    if (value <= 1) return BigInteger.ONE;
    return BigInteger.valueOf(value).multiply(factorial(value - 1));
}
```

PS. Хотя стоит заметить, что вообще если есть решение без рекурсии, то как правило оно будет быстрее работать.

Comment: Evgenii, спасибо!

Comment: а мне не помогло...(
Operator "*" cannot be applied to Java.Math.BigInteger

Comment: @RedCoder попобуйте  return BigInteger.valueOf(value).multiply(factorial(value - 1)), я сейчас ответ поправлю